# How to filter messages from sentry in Next.js using the message text?

Tags: javascript, next.js, sentry

I have tried sentry.init with beforeSend.
It doesn't even log the event.
Can someone help?

I have tried sentry.init with beforeSend.
It doesn't even log the event.